Not able to make socket connection using Socket.io
This is my server code for my project in which am trying to setup video conferencing
This is my github repo link
you can run it and try it yourself using npm start for backend and npm run dev for frontend
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth.js");
const statusmonitor = require("express-status-monitor");

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server();

io.attach(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true, // Allow cookies to be sent with requests
  },
});

app.use(express.json());
app.use(statusmonitor());

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true, // Allow cookies to be sent with requests
  })
);

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
var step = 1;
io.use((socket, next) => {
  console.log(`Client ${socket.id} is attempting to connect at ${new Date().toISOString()}`);
  next();
});
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`${step++} Connection request received by server from client ${socket.id} at ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);

  socket.on("join-room", (roomId, userId) => {
    console.log(` join-room request received by server from client ${userId} at ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
    socket.join(roomId);
    console.log(`User ${userId} joined room ${roomId} successfully at ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
    socket.to(roomId).emit("user-connected", userId);

    // Add listener for disconnection event
    socket.on("User-disconnect", (reason) => {
      console.log(
        `User ${userId} disconnected from room ${roomId} - Reason: ${reason}`
      );
      socket.leave(roomId);
      socket.to(roomId).emit("user-disconnected", userId);

      // Check if the room is empty and clean it up if needed
      const roomUsers = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(roomId);
      if (roomUsers && roomUsers.size === 0) {
        console.log(`Room ${roomId} is empty. Cleaning up.`);
        // Perform cleanup operations (e.g., remove data, release resources)
      }
    });
  });

  socket.on("offer", (data) => {
    console.log(`Offer by client ${data.userId} for ${data.targetUserId} received by server at ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
    
    const offerToEmit = typeof data.offer === "string" ? JSON.parse(data.offer) : data.offer;
    
    socket.to(data.targetUserId).emit("offer", {
      offer: offerToEmit,
      roomId: data.roomId,
      userId: data.userId,
    });
    console.log(`Offer by client ${data.userId} for ${data.targetUserId} emitted by server at ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
  });

  socket.on("answer", (data) => {
    console.log(`Answer by client ${data.userId} for ${data.targetUserId} received by server at ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
    socket.to(data.targetUserId).emit("answer", {
      answer: data.answer,
      roomId: data.roomId,
      userId: data.userId,
    });
    console.log(`Answer by client ${data.userId} for ${data.targetUserId} emitted by server at ${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`);
  });

  socket.on("ice-candidate", (data) => {
    socket.to(data.targetUserId).emit("ice-candidate", {
      candidate: data.candidate,
      roomId: data.roomId,
      userId: data.userId,
    });
  });
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

The problem i am facing is, When i am directly accessing the lobby page or meeting page then i am able to connect to socket and similiarly see remote video calls in the meeting. but when i perform other activities and then try to reidrect to meeting then niether am able to make a socket connection nor i am able to perfrom video conferencing
i noticed that the client is pooling but not recieved by the server.
please somebody help as am stuck on it since long and finding the answer no where. You can check the client code on the github in /frontend/src/pages/meeting.jsx
